# extjs documentation for declarative syntax

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm having a really hard time reading extjs documentation.  I've done a couple successful projects in extjs so far, but I still struggle reading through documentation.  It seems to be written in an imperative style, but all the examples expect a declarative syntax.

For example, if I were to add a tab to TabPanel, I would expect to see in the docs a function called addTab, which takes a tab name and panel like most other UI libraries I've used behave (like Qt or Swing).  Instead, I see a function like `add` which takes a dictionary of values, which don't seem to be documented in the docs themselves.

In an example in extjs 3 docs for TabPanel:

```
var tb = new Ext.Toolbar();
tb.render(document.body);  // toolbar is rendered
tb.add({text:'Button 1'}); // add multiple items (defaultType for Toolbar is 'button')
tb.add({text:'Button 2'});
tb.doLayout();             // refresh the layout
```

In this example, where is the `text` parameter documented?  I've seen examples for adding an `items` field, which I've used before, but what if I just want to add an existing panel?  I assume that's some other keyword, right?  Where are these kinds of things documented?

Answer (score 1):

What you are providing via add() is a component config (or instance of a component if you have one).
"The defaultType is button" means, by default, it will treat your configs (what you pass to add between `{}`) as button configs unless you specify something else via `xtype` attribute.

So in this case `tb.add({text:'Button 1'});`, to know what `text` means, you need to look at button's documentation (config section)

Comment: amol is spot on. It might also be worth expanding that the tb.add({test: 'Button 1'}) example is the 'equivalent' (in terms of final destination, the journey there is a little different because it uses xtypes...) to tb.add(new Ext.Button({text: 'Button 1'})); which is a more explicit way of defining it.

Comment: That helps a bit, but what if I want to add an existing element, for example?  If you didn't know already what keyword to use to add an existing panel from another part of your the code, how would you look that up?